# Modify Header file of Optimizepress [ op_theme_file('header') ]

Tags: php, wordpress

I have tried to edit the default header of Optimizepress, I have edited the blog header, but it seems I can't edit the default page header. On header.php its written

`<?php op_theme_file('header') ?>`

But I don't find the exact location where the header is located to modify.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Landing page : optimizePressTheme/pages/landing/1/template.php

Marketing : optimizePressTheme/pages/marketing/1/template.php

Membership: optimizePressTheme/pages/membership/1/template.php

```
 op_theme_file('header')
```

Where header page  comes from the depend on your page;  it's come from base on landing, marketing, and membership page ...